# Type casting in Apps Script - continued

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Is it only me, or is there a fundamental weakness in GAS in that I can't do something simple like this:

TextBox tb  =  app.getElementById('txtMsg1') as TextBox;

or the equivalent ?

This is critical to development, without having first memorized the entire class library interface, since intellisense (or whatever Google calls it) fails to find appropriate methods on the returned GenericWidget - which I know to be a TextBox.

Perhaps I am missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps Script is JavaScript, and so it is loosely typed. It is indeed an annoyance that JavaScript's untyped nature sometimes makes it impossible to do autocomplete. We have a few thoughts on improving this but so far that's the status.

Answer (score 0):

You will not have to typecast a UI element when you get it by ID. They are automatically get their type. Just use Javascript syntax, not Java.
e.g

```
var myTb = app.getElementById('id_of_my_TB');
myTb.setStyleAttributes({'border': '1px solid red'});
myTb.setValue('A value in textbox');
```

and so on....

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, but I think you are missing the point.

When I do as you suggest, the object 'myTb' is untyped, and so Intellisense can't prompt for methods or members.

Sure, this does not prevent me from developing, but it certainly slows me down.